# What is the proper way to export a NON-singleton class in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I recently learned that all node modules are cached and behave similar to singletons in most instances.

The problem I am trying to solve is to not have every import result in the same instance being returned. This is probably very simple to figure out however I'm having trouble landing on a solid design pattern as I'm new to Node and ES6.

The goals I'm trying to achieve are:

- Private fields
- Consumers of the imported module can new up instances
- instanceof comparison

The best I was able to come up with is the following:

```
export default () => {
   let _foo = 'bar';

   return new class {
      get foo() {
         return _foo;
      }

      set foo(value) {
         _foo = value;
      }
   };
};
```

However this doesn't quite meet all the goals I'm trying to achieve.

Using this method importing modules can't use instanceof to compare prototypes.

It also doesn't matter if importers use the new keyword when creating an instance. Calling `let instance = new Module()` and `let instance = Module()` result in the same thing.

I tried to get around this by removing the new keyword from the functions return however this resulted in the importer having to do the following to get a new instance: `new (Module())`

I have also tried exporting constructor functions but this resulted in the loss of private fields.

***What is the proper way to export a constructor function/class from a node module?***

***UPDATE:***

After playing around some more I was able to come up with the following:

```
const _sFoo = Symbol();

export default class {
   constructor() {
      this[_sFoo] = 'default';
   }

   get foo() {
      return this[_sFoo];
   }

   set foo(value) {
      this[_sFoo] = value;
   }
}
```

This seems to meet all of my goals however I'm still not sure if this is the best design pattern...

Comment: Your scheme for private member variables can be seen from the outside via `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)`.  There is not an ES6 defined way to do truly private members.  The only way to get true privacy that I know is still this: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html.  Lots of discussion here: https://www.google.com/search?q=private+members+in+es6

Comment: It is as simple as exporting a class, I'm not sure why this is even discussed. I would suggest to KISS and follow `_foo` naming convention. Having 'really private' symbol props complicates debugging and testing and doesn't help anything.

Comment: @estus I realize now that it was just as simple as exporting a class. What I was getting hung up on was that the fields defined outside of the class definition were shared across multiple instances. I'm still torn on whether to use naming convention or symbols to define "private" fields. I'm starting to lean more towards just using naming convention since fields aren't truly private.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you use naming conventions like ```_foo``` or symbols to denote that fields/funcs shouldn't be used?

Comment: I've tried this pattern when Symbol has appeared, and it was awful. You will hardly see it in nice production code.  Yes, 'private' field becomes a trap at the moment when you need to access it from the outside - for testing, extending, whatever. _ prefix and non-enumerable descriptor is enough.

Comment: In 99% of my cases, I just prefix a normal property with `_` to denote a private property and rely on the convention more than actual privacy.  I sometimes create it with `Object.defineProperty()` to make it so it is not enumerable.  Only a few times have I found it justified to go to the trouble of making a truly private property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem I am trying to solve is to not have every import result in the same instance being returned. This is probably very simple to figure out however I'm having trouble landing on a solid design pattern as I'm new to Node and ES6.

You have a couple options:

1. You can export the constructor and let the code that is loading your module call that constructor to create their own object.  This allows the calling code to create as many independent objects as they desired.  Exporting a constructor would require `new` to be used by the caller unless the constructor explicitly detects they were called without `new` and then adapts to still return a new instance.
2. You can export a factory function and let the code that is loading your module call that factory function to create as many of their own objects as they want.  The factory function would be just called as a normal function and it would return a new object each time it was called.
3. You can export a method that, when called, does whatever you want including creating the desired object and returning it (perhaps embedded in an object of other things too).  This is just a variant of the factory function, but may include a bunch of things at once.

> The goals I'm trying to achieve are:
>
> Private fields

The above do not help you at all with private fields per object.  That is a completely separate discussion.

> Consumers of the imported module can new up instances

Option 1 above allows the caller to use `new` directly.  The other options are factory functions so they would not use `new`.

> instanceof comparison

You have to export the constructor directly (option 1 above) in order to use `instanceof` with it.  The other options don't export the constructor so you don't have anything to use `instanceof` with.

> What is the proper way to export a constructor function/class from a node module?

You just export the constructor.  In Javascript, constructors are just functions so you just export the constructor and then the caller can use `let x = new SomeConstructor()` to create their own object.  They can likewise use `if (x instanceof SomeConstructor)`.  With ES6 syntax, you just export the class name and that's equivalent to exporting the constructor.

Comment: Personally I'd say constructor is the only option unless 1. you're not doing OO (which is fine BTW) and treat objects simply as namespaces or 2. your constructor takes too many arguments that it is better to use a builder

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your input. I ended up going the constructor route.